# Conversion failed with a declared variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting this error when trying to write this stored procedure in SQL Server. For the life of me, I do not know why. Any clues?

```
BEGIN
declare @output varchar(max)

select @output = COALESCE(@output + ',','') + CONVERT(varchar(150), AGE_START)
from tblRaceCategories
where RACE_ID = 13

return @output
END
```

The error I am getting is:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5,8,11,16,21,31,41,51,61,16,21,31,41,51,61' to data type int.

Which does not make sense, I have declared `@output` as `varchar`, I have converted my `AGE_START` to `varchar`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A return value can only be of the type `int`, that's where the conversion fails.

Use an output variable instead of returning the string. Example:

```
create procedure Demo
  @output varchar(max) out
as
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. Ended up having to create a FUNCTION for what I was intending to do, but that did solve that problem.  Thanks.